# How to scroll bottom of div at launch?

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, scroll

I need to create a chat for my application, and to show the last messages when going on the chat page, I need to scroll automatically at the bottom of the div.

VueJs :

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="comments" v-chat-scroll>
            <div v-for="comment in comments">
                //What defines the comment
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS :

```
.comments {
    margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
    max-width: 60.75rem;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Typescript :

```
export default {

    mounted() {
        this.scrollToEnd();
    },

    methods: {

        scrollToEnd() {
            var container = this.$el.querySelector(".comments");
            var scrollHeight = container.scrollHeight;
            container.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
        },
    }
}
```

I tried to use scrollTop by giving the scrollHeight of the div with the scroll.
scrollHeight get the good value (in this case 300), but scrollTop stays at 0.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me as is, without the `v-chat-scroll`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    comments: Array.from({
      length: 50
    }, (_, i) => 'Comment ' + i).concat(['last comment - scroll here'])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.scrollToEnd();
  },

  methods: {

    scrollToEnd() {
      var container = this.$el.querySelector(".comments");
      var scrollHeight = container.scrollHeight;
      container.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.comments {
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
  max-width: 60.75rem;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.comment {
  padding: 4px;
  border-top: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="comments">
    <div v-for="comment in comments">
      <div class="comment">{{comment}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Also, the `v-chat-scroll` directive does the same thing, it works for me too:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    comments: Array.from({length: 50}, (_,i) => 'Comment '+i).concat(['last comment - scroll here'])
  },
})
```

```css
.comments {
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
  max-width: 60.75rem;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.comment{
  padding: 4px;
  border-top: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="comments" v-chat-scroll>
    <div v-for="comment in comments">
      <div class="comment">{{comment}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-chat-scroll/dist/vue-chat-scroll.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It wasn't working at the time I tried it but now it does, thanks ! At the time I had also the mounted hook with the scrollTop, so maybe it was because it "canceled" the v-chat-scroll ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. Though when I try it with both, it seems to work too. I initially though it is an issue with rendering, and you have to run `scrollToEnd()` in a `Vue.nextTick()`, but that doesn't seem to be necessary either. Well, glad that it's working!

Answer (score 0):

the function [`.scrollIntoView(false)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) should scroll you to the bottom of a div. I have added a codesnippet, but this is just made out of html,js,css just to show how it works.

```js
entity = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  newItem = entity.children[0].children[0].cloneNode();
  newItem.innerText = i;
  entity.children[0].appendChild(newItem);
}

function f(){
  entity.children[0].scrollIntoView(false);
}
```

```css
.text{
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: red solid 
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div>
  <p>txt</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button onClick="f()">scroll to bottom</button>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me